# Prevent Kendo Grid from auto saving

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

How can I stop the kendo grid/datasource automatically posting changes to the server?

I've tried intercepting Grid's saveChanges but it isn't being triggered by the Updated command. As per the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/autosync), DataSource's auto-sync by default should be false, but I went ahead and set it anyway but to no effect.

```
$("#items-grid").kendoGrid({
 dataSource: {
autoSync: false,
type: "json",
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("
        ItemList ", "
        PurchaseRequisition ", new {prId = @Model.Id }))",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
    },
    update: {
        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("
        ItemEdit ", "
        PurchaseRequisition "))",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
    }
},
sync: function(e) {
    console.log("sync complete");
},
schema: {
    data: "Data",
    total: "Total",
    errors: "Errors",
    model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
            /...
        }
    }
},
 },
  saveChanges: function(e) {
  // not fired from  Update command
  e.preventDefault();
 },
  columns: [{
// ...
   }, {
     command: [{
    name: "edit",
    text: {
        edit: "Edit",
        update: "Update",
        cancel: "Cancel"
    }
}],
width: 100

  }]
});
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `dataSource` batch set to `true`.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {...},
  batch: true
  ...}

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  navigatable: true,
  pageable: true,
  height: 550,
  toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
  columns: [...],
  editable: true
});
```

**NOTE**: this is inline editing.

You can see an example on the official page: [Batch editing](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing)

Comment: No luck. I also tried using the toolbar:[] and not the column commands.